# How to escape strings in for use in bash/sh via PHP's shell_exec?

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, unix

I've been calling more advanced shell commands from PHP recently using `shell_exec`

As my commands become more complicated, I keep experiencing errors with things not being escaped properly.  I want to be able to call `shell_exec('echo '.$variable)` and no matter what I put in `$variable` it will just echo it. Some things $variable could include are ``` $ ~ ' " \n \r \c `` ( ) { } ; \ ```

What's the best way to escape a shell command before executing it?

Comment: Does PHP not have a way of passing command-line args as an array of strings? Do you **really** want to be passing these args to a **shell** function, or are you just trying to invoke a program? If you bypass the shell completely you won't have to escape your strings at all.

Comment: I really do want to pass the args to a shell function. `escapeshellarg` did what i wanted it to do - i just didn't know about it. I'm using PHP to parse data and I'm passing the output to CocoaDialog. The resulting (parsed) data has a lot of strange characters in it. Also, to everyone else, I'm not sure why this question was down voted. I think it's a legitimate question and I didn't realize there was a function to solve the problem - even after much ineffective googling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does [`escapeshellcmd`](http://php.net/escapeshellcmd) or [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) not do what you want?

```
shell_exec('echo '. escapeshellarg($variable));
```

Comment: it got me pointed in the right direction. `escapeshellarg` is what actually worked best.